# Why doesn't this chat message show up as me having starred it?

Tags: bug, chat, chat-stars

Over in [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq), I starred [this message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35731042#35731042) a while ago. However, now it is not showing up as me having starred it. Here's what I see on the board:

[image]

So I clicked on it, and got the 'It is too late to undo this operation':

[image]

Reloading doesn't do anything.

Why is my star not showing up?

Answer (score 9):

The stars on that message were cleared when it was unpinned; it was re-pinned a short while later. Your star was one of the original stars, so got cleared when it was unpinned. You can't star it twice; the error message here is wrong, but that's what's going on.