# Make the error message when I attempt to re-star a chat message where my star was cleared more understandable

Tags: bug, chat, error-message, chat-stars

I recently starred a message, but my star was cleared by a room owner. I attempted to star it again, but the system (rightfully) prevented me from doing so. However, the error message I got when I attempted to re-star that message was:

> It is too late to undo this operation

This error message [is extremely confusing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291881/why-doesnt-this-chat-message-show-up-as-me-having-starred-it). It seems as though the system thinks I'm trying to undo my old star, which is (of course) too late to undo. But my star was already undone by an RO; I'm trying to *redo* it.

Can this error message please be made more clear? Here's an example:

> Your previous star on this message has been cleared; you cannot star it again

**Update:** When one attempts to re-star a message where their previous star was cleared by a room owner *just* after the original star, during the period when the user can normally undo it. a different message shows:

> You have already voted, but the voting has been cleared by a moderator

However, after that period, apparently the "too late" message takes precedence over it. Thus, this is more of a bug rather than a feature request. Also, there's the issue that the error message always says "moderator", even when a non-moderator room owner cleared the stars.

Comment: I'm willing to conjecture that this happens so infrequently that it doesn't really merit a code change to cope with it.  If a room owner clears a star, you're pretty much obliged to accept it and move on.

Comment: @Snow Some users just aren't aware that their star was cleared. They star something, then suddenly see that the star is gone, and think their star didn't go through, and so try again. It'd be nice if the error message clearly stated that the prior attempt indeed went through but was cleared.